# Como hacer un Query con Ajax después de una inserción

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, post, insert

Después de una inserción exitosa con Ajax de una entrada, me gustaría ver cuál es la ID y la URL de esa misma entrada y mostrarla en una ventana modal sin actualizar la página

```
    <script>
        
        $("#enquiry_email_form").on("submit", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
 
            var form= $(this);
            var ajaxurl = form.data("url");
            var detail_info = {
                post_title: form.find("#post_title").val(),
                post_description: form.find("#post_description").val()
            }
 
            if(detail_info.post_title === "" || detail_info.post_description === "") {
                alert("Fields cannot be blank");
                return;
            }
 
            $.ajax({
 
                url: ajaxurl,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    post_details : detail_info,
                    action: 'save_post_details_form' // this is going to be used inside wordpress functions.php// *esto se utilizará dentro de las functions.php*
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert("Insert Failed" + error);
                },
      success: function(response) {
                modal.style.display = "block";  * abre la ventana modal*

                body.style.position = "static";
                body.style.height = "100%";
                body.style.overflow = "hidden";
                     
                     
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
<button id="btnModal">Abrir modal</button> 
<div id="tvesModal" class="modalContainer">
 <div class="modal-content">
 <span class="close">×</span> <h2>Modal</h2> * Ventana modal mostrar le url y ID generado *
 <p><?php ***echo $title_post, $url, $ID*** ?></p> 
 
 </div>
 </div>
```

¿Alguna forma de obtener esos datos desde  `success: function(response) {}`?

Este es el codigo que tengo para hacer una nueva entrada con ajax el cual funciona perfecto:

Archivo **functions.php**

```
function save_enquiry_form_action() {
 
    $post_title = $_POST['post_details']['post_title'];
    $post_description = $_POST['post_details']['post_description'];
    $args = [
        'post_title'=> $post_title,
        'post_content'=>$post_description,
        'post_status'=> 'publish',
        'post_type'=> 'post',
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'post_date'=> get_the_date()
    ];
 
    $is_post_inserted = wp_insert_post($args);
 
    if($is_post_inserted) {
        return "success";
    } else {
        return "failed";
    }
}
```

Todo funciona bien, los datos se insertan en la tabla de mi base de datos.

Les agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

la función `wp_insert_post()` si es exitosa devuelve el id del post creado, sin embargo si falla puedes usar is_wp_error() para verificar el error, con esos datos en mente puedes hacer algo como esto.

```
// Datos del post

$args = array(
    'post_title'    => 'Tu titulo',
    'post_content'  => 'Tu Contenido',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'show_in_rest'  => true,
    'post_date'     => get_the_date()
);

// Insertamos el post

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $args );

// Verificamos si hay error
if ( is_wp_error( $post_id ) ) {

    // Retornamos una respuesta
    $post_result = array( 
        'error'     => $post_id->get_error_message(),
        'message'   => 'Vaya, algo salio mal!',
    );

} else {

    // En caso de ser exitoso retornamos la información del post

    $post_result = array( 
        'post_id'   => $post_id,
        'url'       => get_the_permalink( $post_id ),
        'post_name' => get_the_title( $post_id ),
    );

}

echo json_encode( $post_result );
```

Luego en tu success recuperas esa información

```
success: function( response ) {

    // Como nuestra respuesta es texto plano la convertimos en JSON

    let response_json = JSON.parse( response );

    // Verificamos el estatus de la respuesta

    if ( response_json.error ) {

        console.log( response_json.error );
        console.log( response_json.message );

    } else {

        console.log( response_json.post_id );
        console.log( response_json.url );
        console.log( response_json.post_name );

    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta , lo probe pero me aparece como "undefined" en la consola ¿faltara algo mas?

Comment: @juan Undefined es porque la variable no ha sido declarada, en tu success agrega un console log de la variable response para ver que te muestra, agrégalo como primera linea en tu success, si recibes undefined trata de ver que es lo que no esta definido, generalmente recibes el mensaje de error mas el numero de linea donde esta el error.